# Using Log4Fx to log button clicks in states in Flex application

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4, flash-builder

I want to use [Log4Fx](http://cleartoolkit.com/?page_id=31) to log button clicks from a state as i have a state based application with transitions. So on each button click I want to log which state was the user in while he clicked the button because the state change happens on a button click. Can someone suggest a code snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would think it would look something like:

```
<mx:LinkButton label=”Hello world again!” click=”logger.info("ButtonNameHere -- state: " + currentState);”/>
```